# how seo optimize a bunch of similar images?

Tags: image, seo, meta-tags, googlebot

For example I have a website consists of 1000 images that are in a similar subject (for example: bedroom decoration design).

When define meta tags, alt text and image file name, logically many of the 1000 images would have a similar file names, tags, alt texts and...

Does this issue affect Google Bots to detect my site as a site with many duplicated content?
If yes, what is the solution?

Example of images definition:

```
image1:  
name: bedroom-decoration-design-1.jpg  
alt text: bedroom decoration design  
description: new decoration designs for your bedroom
```

...

```
image2:  
name: bedroom-decoration-design-2.jpg  
alt text: bedroom decoration design  
description: new decoration designs for your bedroom
```

...

```
image3:  
name: bedroom-decoration-design-3.jpg  
alt text: bedroom decoration design  
description: new decoration designs for your bedroom
```

...

Answer (score 2):

the best thing you should do is review the Image publishing guidelines over on the Google Webmaster Tools. This will give you detailed insight on what to do when it comes to images and ALT tags. My advice would be to come up with creative ways to use the keywords that best describe the product. See example below:

```
image1:  
name: decorative-bedroom-design-one.jpg  
alt text: creative bedroom decorations
description: stylish designs for your bedroom
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate content appears on text and not on image name and alt attributes. Moreover, your images don't have the same name.

However, your images name contain all the same three keywords. I'm not sure but I guess these keywords can be considered by Google as keywords stuffing (images name too much optimized). And Google can decide to penalize your website.

If I were you, I would try to give specific name of image in relation to what image shows to alternate keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can add different synonyms, related searches, and other relevant variations with your bedroom decoration design keywords and add in image name, alt tag and description tag.

For Example image1: name: glamorous-bedroom-decoration-design.jpg alt text: glamorous bedroom decoration design description: glamorous designs for your bedroom decoration.

image2: name: traditional-bedroom-decoration-design.jpg alt text: traditional bedroom decoration design description: traditional designs for your bedroom decoration

image3: name: bedroom-color-schemes.jpg alt text: bedroom color schemes description: Best color scheme for your bedroom decoration design

image4: name: night-bedroom-decoration-design.jpg alt text: night bedroom decoration design description: night bedroom decoration ideas

image5: name: wedding-bedroom-decoration-design.jpg alt text: wedding bedroom decoration design description: wedding bedroom decoration ideas

Answer (score 0):

use synonyms, swap words, add / remove individual words, use plural & singular, different variations, jargon words related to what the image's / site's about